# Data structure for "limited memory map"

Tags: memory, data-structures, hashmap

I want to implement an associative collection, mapping keys K to values V. I further want to associate each value V with a weight, so we have Map[K → (V, Double)].

The idea now is to have a limited memory version of this collection, which only stores elements beyond a weight threshold t. With each insertion of an element e into this collection, we increase the weight of e by some amount, e.g. 1, and decay the weight of all other elements e' != e by some decay factor, say 0.0001.
This ensures that elements present in this collection are either a. *recent*, or b. *frequent*.

Of course, one could implement a naive version of such a data structure, which actively performs decay operations, and checks for voilations of threshold t for all elements. That would be terribly inefficient.

I am wondering if there already is a data structure out there which does exactly that. Maybe there is a related datastructure which I could use to implement my requirements. Input is appreciated.

Comment: I created what I called an MRU Dictionary in C# some time back, that does essentially what you're asking, although the decay is proportional to the size of the cache. You can see the article at http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=626

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a variation on an LFU (Least Frequently Used) cache eviction policy, where the decision to evict takes into account an additional threshold based on the relative proportion of updates.

You would not necessarily need to actively decay all other entries when inserting - just retain the total number of inserts across all elements such that you can calculate whether to retain a particular eviction candidate by evaluating whether it exceeds the threshold at that point.

A slightly different approach, without the use of weights, would be to store the keys in buckets by time, where the key to value lookup was done within the context of a specific bucket.

- Each bucket would have an associated time range within which values could be inserted into the bucket.
- Each bucket would internally have a `K -> V` map.
- An additional map of `K -> Bucket` would be retained.
- Buckets would be inserted into an ordered list.

Insertion into the data structure would:

- Allocate a new current bucket if now is outside the valid time range for the most recent bucket.
- Check whether `K` already existed in a bucket
- If it does not, insert `K -> V` into the current bucket and `K -> current` into the key to bucket map.
- If it exists in the current (most recent) bucket, do nothing.
- If it exist in an older bucket, move it to the current bucket and update the bucket map.

Things that are used recently move up into the more recent buckets. Things that are not end up in the older buckets. Periodically you purge older buckets.

A downside is the use of time to decay, although you could probably use the approach you describe above at the bucket level, so reducing the cost as a result of the smaller number of buckets than items in the collection to an acceptable level.

Comment: That's a good observation. However, an LFU does not take into account recency. The only criterion for cache eviction is the absolute access number. In my model, an entry which has been accessed 1000 times but a million inserts back would get evicted long before an item that was only accessed 10 times just now. Note that I am not implementing a cache here - I actually need the datastructure to balance frequency with recency (which is tuneable by the decay factor).

Comment: It would be interesting to simulate both behaviours (LFU and a naive implementation of what you describe above) and see how much the behaviour varies. Thinking aloud, things that are being updated less frequently will probably on average be updated less recently unless individual keys are updated several times in a cluster then not for an extended period of time, and so it might be a good enough approximation depending on your intended use and update pattern.

Comment: And snap, your comment update says the same thing I was thinking :)